# operator bool() converted to std::string and conflict with operator std::string()

Tags: c++, type-conversion

How can operator bool() cause an error when declaring operator std::string in a class and also serving as an implicit conversion to string by itself?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    operator std::string() { cout << "op string" << endl; return "whatever";}
    operator bool() { cout << "op bool" << endl; return true;}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string s;
    Test t;
    s = t;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to go ahead and `using namespace std;` why do you go on to clarify `std::string`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you are facing (besides `operator std::string()` returning a bool) is that implicit conversions trigger when you want and when you don't.

When the compiler sees `s = t` it identifies the following potential `std::operator=` matches:

```
// using std::string for compactness instead of the full template
std::string::operator=( std::string const & ); 
std::string::operator=( char );
```

Now, `t` is neither of them, so it tries to *convert* it to something that can fit and finds two paths: convert to bool that can be promoted to `char` or convert to `std::string` directly. The compiler cannot really decide and gives up.

This is one of the reasons that you want to avoid providing many different conversion operators. Anything that can be implicitly called by the compiler will eventually be called when you don't think it should.

This [article](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html) specifically deals with this problem. The suggestion is instead of providing a conversion to `bool`, provide a conversion to a member function

```
class testable {
   typedef void (testable::*bool_type)();
   void auxiliar_function_for_true_value() {}
public:
   operator bool_type() const {
      return condition() ? &testable::auxiliar_function_for_true_value : 0;
   }
   bool condition() const;
};
```

If an instance of this class is used inside a condition (`if (testable())`) the compiler will try and convert to `bool_type` that can be used in a condition.

**EDIT**:

After the comment on how the code is more complex with this solution, you can always provide it as a generic small utility. Once you provide the first part of the code, the complexity is encapsulated in the header.

```
// utility header safe_bool.hpp
class safe_bool_t;
typedef void (safe_bool_t::*bool_type)();
inline bool_type safe_bool(bool);

class safe_bool_t {
   void auxiliar_function_for_true_value() {}
   friend bool_type safe_bool(bool);
};
inline bool_type safe_bool(bool)
{
   return condition ? &safe_bool_t::auxiliar_function_for_true_value : 0;
}
```

Your class now becomes much more simple, and it is readable in itself (by choosing appropriate names for the functions and types):

```
// each class with conversion
class testable {
public:
   operator bool_type() {
      return safe_bool(true);
   }
};
```

Only if the reader is interested in knowing how the `safe_bool` idiom is implemented and reads the header they fill be faced with the complexity (which can be explained in comments)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the `safe_bool` idiom. Most of the times you don't really want a boolean, you just want to be able to write the `if` test :)

Comment: I assume bool is being converted to char through integer promotion, since the standard doesn't say anything about bool conversions to char.
Quoting: "An rvalue of type bool can be converted to an rvalue of type int, with false being zero and true becoming one."

Comment: Very interesting article, but i find it very unreadable to use such code for provinding an if test, it defeats the purpose of adding readability. Also auxiliar function should be const.

Comment: It always depends on what side of the library you are in. While implementing the class this is more complex than the `bool` conversion, so you might think that it defeats the whole purpose. On the other hand, from user code it is much simpler. If you are implementing (just an example) a smart pointer, there is a single implementation point where you add the extra 5 lines (the smart pointer itself) and infinite potential places where user code might benefit from the simpler test syntax: `if (ptr && ptr->operation())`

Comment: I have edited the answer to give an example of how the complexity can be encapsulated in a small header so that you do not need to provide that for each of the types you implement with the conversion

Answer (score 4):

Your operator std::string() needs to return a string, not a bool.

Comment: It returns a string, `std::string(static_cast<const char*>(true))`

Comment: Fixed the typo, but it's irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 1):

As David Rodriguez correctly points out, a `bool` can be promoted to `char` and you get an ambigous overload.

In the stl, making a class testable is usually done via a conversion to a `void *`, e.g. when you do

```
while (istream.getline()) {
}
```

The loop condition resolves to false because istream returns NULL in it's [operator void*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/operator_voidpt/).

Some people argue this is not that good of a solution as in theory one could do

```
void* streamptr = istream;
delete streamptr;
```

But in my opinion, if someone starts to delete pointers like that... he shouldn't be allowed anywhere near stl code (or C++ for that matter).